# неправильная запись в словарь и в csv: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.5

не могу залить в csv файл словарь.
Код залива в csv

```
import csv
parsing_data = [{'phrase': 'пс4', 'num': '88\xa0910', 'link': '/#!/?words=%D0%BF%D1%814'}, {'phrase': 'пс4 купить', 'num': '16\xa0207', 'link': '/#!/?words=%D0%BF%D1%814%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C'}]
output_file = open("pr1.csv", "w")
wrtr = csv.
DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=["phrase", "num", "link"])
wrtr.writerow(["phrase", "num", "link"])
wrtr.writerow(parsing_data)
```

в фразе пс4 num должно равняться 88 910, в пс4 купить 16 207.
если после парсинга выводить num(как переменную), то все выводится корректно, после записи в словарь происходит вот такое преобразование. Как можно исправить ситуацию?

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/parserwordstat/parse.py", line 147, in <module>
    parse()
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/parserwordstat/parse.py", line 106, in parse
    parse()
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/parserwordstat/parse.py", line 111, in parse
    end_programm(parsing_data)
  File "/home/ti/PycharmProjects/parserwordstat/parse.py", line 19, in end_programm
    wrtr.writerow(["phrase", "num", "link"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 150, in <genexpr>
    return (rowdict.get(key, self.restval) for key in self.fieldnames)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Оформите код так, чтобы мы могли его запустить и получить такую же ошибку, а то сейчас там вообще ошибки синтаксиса есть

Comment: Исправил код, сделал его компелируемым

Answer (score 2):

Так как вы работаете с объектом типа `DictWriter`, методу `writerow` нужно передавать не `list`, а `dict` объект. Поэтому у вас и возникает ошибка `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Пример:

```
import csv

data = [
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "city": "Moscow"},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "city": "Khabarovsk"},
    {"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "city": "Sahalin"}
]

with open("file.csv", "w", newline="") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=data[0].keys())
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: полностью с вами согласен